# What are the 16 realms in Ninjago?

Tags: lego, lego-ninjago-masters-of-spinjitzu

Realm 1 is the Realm of the Oni and the Dragon. There's the realm which the ninjas reside in.

What are in the other 14 realms?

Answer (score 9):

The [fandom wiki](https://ninjago.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sixteen_Realms) website gives a nice overview over the known realms at this time:

> List of Realms:
>
> ◾Ninjago Island
>
> ◾Underworld
>
> ◾Realm of Madness
>
> ◾Cloud Kingdom
>
> ◾Cursed Realm (Destroyed due to immense flooding from
> the Endless Sea)
>
> ◾Chima
>
> ◾Djinjago (Destroyed in consequence to the
> destruction of the Cursed Realm)
>
> ◾Realm of Oni and Dragons
>
> ◾Departed Realm
>
> ◾Never-Realm
>
> ◾6 other unknown realms.

There can you find more information about the single realms too.